# Trying to achieve search bar look from Amazon.com

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="input-group">
<select class="input-group-addon">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
</select>

<input id="email" type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email">

<button class="input-group-addon">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Can someone help me achieve this look?
[image]

I'm just completely lost and baffled why this is what I get
[image]

http://codepen.io/jpezninjo/pen/bgVyZp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```css
select {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}
button {
  padding: 6px 12px;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
}
.input-group-addon {
  padding: 0!important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron-narrow/jumbotron-narrow.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
      <select>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
    </select>
  </span>

      <input id="email" type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email">

      <span class="input-group-addon"> <button>Submit</button></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was actually a simple fix lol and I'm surprised. But there's no way I could ever have thought to do this

Answer (score 0):

**Updated...**

Using Bootstrap. You can try this. Not require any css style.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">    
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
      <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                     <span id="search_concept">All</span> <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                      <li><a href="#contains">test1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#its_equal">test2</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#greather_than">test3</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#less_than">test4</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#all">test5</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="search_param" value="all" id="search_param">         
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="x" placeholder="Search term...">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! I'd like to not have to use JS but I did appreciate learning that I could make a dropdown with li's. Btw, what does col-xs-offset-2 do/accomplish that I wasn't?